# How to make the size of table view depending upon number of rows in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have 3 rows in my table view.I have made a custom cell.Now on running the on diffrent devices i want to make the height of table view as three cell can fit into it.On iPad it works fine but on iPhone it takes little more space in bottom so please tell how can i get the dynamic height for each device.

I am using the following approach.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    float main_height=self.table_view.frame.size.height;
    float result_cell_height;
    float percentage = (77.0 / 568.0);
    float height = self.view.frame.size.height * percentage;
    result_cell_height=(height>77.0)?height:77.0;
    if(height>main_height/3)
    {
        NSLog(@"con true");
        result_cell_height=main_height/3;
    }
    NSLog(@"result height is %f",result_cell_height);

    return result_cell_height;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: that method doesnt change the tableview height!! That is for row height!!!! I assume you are trying to change the cell height so that the tableview will have 3 cells fit in it!!! is that right ?

Comment: collection of row height will change the table height i guess

Comment: See my concern is as height of table should collective height of three cells or height of each cell should be as big so three cells can fit into the table view

Comment: Your code has a serious problem. You are basing the height of the cell on the height of the table. But you are asking how to base the height of the table on the total height of the cells. One of the two needs to be fixed. Both heights can't be based on each other.

Comment: no row height has nothing to do with tableheight. If you want to change table height, you need to set the frame of your tableview based on your row height multiplied by 3 @deepakkumar

Answer (score 0):

```
float myHeight = self.view.frame.size.height * (77/568);
[self.table_view setFrame:(CGRect){0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, myHeight}];
```

You said you want the table to resize for different devices, so that will do it. You also said you want it to fit exactly 3 cells, so:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    float myHeight = self.view.frame.size.height * (77/568);
    return myHeight / 3;
}
```

If instead you want the cells to be a consistent size and the table's size to be based on that (I recommend this), then:

```
#define ROW_HEIGHT 40.0f

...

self.table_view setFrame:(CGRect){0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, ROW_HEIGHT * 3}];

...

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return ROW_HEIGHT;
}
```